# How do I make this Angular D3.JS Chart Style and add Links to each pie?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I took this [Khan Academy section](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/trigonometry) and turned it into [this](http://codepen.io/roadtocode/pen/obovYE):
I would like to do a few more things
1) Change the styling of the breadcrumbs
2) Change the colours of each wheel the way I'd like it
3) When people click on a section of the wheel, i'd like a div to appear at the bottom that show more details about that particular section and a link to KA's website for the corresponding section
Any guidance on how to do this will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Here's the JS:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app',['nvd3'] )

app.controller('ClusterWheelCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

    // Breadcrumb dimensions: width, height, spacing, width of tip/tail.
    $scope.breadcrumbs='';
    $scope.data = {"name": ""};
    $scope.elementObjects = {"name": ""};

    $scope.options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'sunburstChart',
            height: 450,
            color: d3.scale.category20c(),
            transitionDuration: 250,
            sunburst: {
                dispatch: {
                    chartClick: function(e) {       
                      console.log($scope.data)
                        updateBreadcrumbs($scope.data.reverse(), '')
                    },
                    elementMouseover: function (e) {
                        function getElementNames(obj) {
                            var result = [obj];
                            if (obj.parent) {
                                result = result.concat(getElementNames(obj.parent));
                            }
                            return result;
                        }
                        var sequenceArray = getElementNames(e.data);
                        $scope.data = sequenceArray;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

        // Breadcrumb dimensions: width, height, spacing, width of tip/tail.
        var b = { w: 125, h: 30, s: 3, t: 10 };
initializeBreadcrumbTrail()
function initializeBreadcrumbTrail() {
  // Add the svg area.
  var trail = d3.select("#sequence").append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", 750)
      .attr("height", 50)
      .attr("id", "trail");
  // Add the label at the end, for the percentage.
  trail.append("svg:text")
    .attr("id", "endlabel")
    .style("fill", "#000");
}

// Generate a string that describes the points of a breadcrumb polygon.
function breadcrumbPoints(d, i) {
  var points = [];
  points.push("0,0");
  points.push(b.w + ",0");
  points.push(b.w + b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
  points.push(b.w + "," + b.h);
  points.push("0," + b.h);
  if (i > 0) { // Leftmost breadcrumb; don't include 6th vertex.
    points.push(b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
  }
  return points.join(" ");
}

// Update the breadcrumb trail to show the current sequence and percentage.
function updateBreadcrumbs(nodeArray, percentageString) {

  // Data join; key function combines name and depth (= position in sequence).
  var g = d3.select("#trail")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(nodeArray, function(d) { return d.name + d.depth; });

  // Add breadcrumb and label for entering nodes.
  var entering = g.enter().append("svg:g");

  entering.append("svg:polygon")
      .attr("points", breadcrumbPoints)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return 'deepskyblue'; });

  entering.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", (b.w + b.t) / 2)
      .attr("y", b.h / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  // Set position for entering and updating nodes.
  g.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + i * (b.w + b.s) + ", 0)";
  });

  // Remove exiting nodes.
  g.exit().remove();

  // Now move and update the percentage at the end.
  d3.select("#trail").select("#endlabel")
      .attr("x", (nodeArray.length + 0.5) * (b.w + b.s))
      .attr("y", b.h / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(percentageString);

  // Make the breadcrumb trail visible, if it's hidden.
  d3.select("#trail")
      .style("visibility", "");

}


        $scope.data = [{
            "name": "Introduction to Trigonometry by Khan Academy",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Trigonometry with right triangles",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Introduction to the trigonometric ratios",
                          "children": [
                                {"name": "Opposite, adjacent, and hypotenuse (sides of right triangles)", "size": 15},
                                {"name": "Introduction to the trigonometric ratios", "size": 0},
                                {"name": "Finding trig ratios in right triangles", "size": 55},
                                {"name": "How to find trigonometric ratios in a right triangle (examples)"},

{"name": "Find trigonometric ratios in right triangles", "size": 15}
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Solving for a side in a right triangle using the trigonometric ratios",
                            "children": [
                                {"name": "Finding an unknown side in a right triangle using trigonometry", "size": 3534},
                                {"name": "How to find missing sides in a right triangle using trigonometry (example)", "size": 5731},
                                {"name": "Solve for a side in a right triangle", "size": 7840}
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Solving for an angle in a right triangle using the trigonometric ratios",
                            "children": [
                                {"name": "Inverse trig functions introduction", "size": 7074},
{"name": "Solve for an angle in a right triangle"}
                            ]
                        },
{"name": "Modeling with Right Triangles",
"children": [
  {"name": "How to solve a right triangle word problem with a missing angle (example)"},
  {"name": "Angles of elevation and depression"},
  {"name": "Right triangle word problems"}
]
},
{"name": "Trigonometric Ratios and Similarities",
"children": [
  {"name": "Triangle similarity and the trigonometric ratios"},
  {"name": "Challenge problem: Verify identities"},
  {"name": "Challenge problem: Match trigonometric values and side ratios"}
]
},
{"name": "Sine and Cosine of Complementary Angles",
"children": [
  {"name": "The sine and cosine of complementary example"},
  {"name": "Using the relationship between sine and cosine of complementary angles to solve a geometry problem"},
  {"name": "Using the relationship between sine and cosine of complementary angles to solve a real-world problem"}
]
},
{"name": "Trigonometric Ratios of Special Triangles",
"children": [
  {"name": "Trig ratios of special triangles"}
]
},
{"name": "Introduction to the Pythagorean Trigonometric Identity",
"children": [
  {"name": "Introduction to the Pythagorean trigonometric identity"}
]
},
{"name": "The reciprocal Trig Ratios",
"children": [
  {"name": "Reciprocal trig ratios (cosecant, secant, and cotangent)"},
  {"name": "How to find the reciprocal trigonometric ratios of an angle (example)"},
  {"name": "How to use cotangent in order to solve for a side in a right triangle (example)"},
  {"name": "Sine, cosine, and cofunctions"}
]
}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Trigonometry with General Triangles",
                    "children": [
                        {"name": "The Law of Sines", "size": 17010,
                        "children": [
                        {"name": "How to find a missing side length using the law of sines (example)"},
                        {"name": "How to find a missing angle measure using the law of sines (example)"},
                        {"name": "Solve triangles using the law of sines"},
                        {"name": "Proof of the law of sines"}
                        ]
                        },
                        {"name": "The Law of Cosines", "size": 5842,
                        "children": [
                        {"name": "How to find a missing side length using the law of cosines (example)"},
                        {"name": "How to find a missing angle measure using the law of cosines (example)"},
                        {"name": "Solve triangles using the law of cosines"},
                        {"name": "Proof of the law of cosines"}
                        ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Solving General Triangles",
                            "children": [
                                {"name": "Word problem: Solving for a side length in a general triangle (example)", "size": 1983},
                                {"name": "General triangle word problems", "size": 2047}
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "The unit circle definition of sine, cosine, and tangent",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Introduction to Radians",
                            "children": [
                                {"name": "Introduction to radians", "size": 721},
                                {"name": "Converting between radians and degrees", "size": 4294},
                                {"name": "How to convert from degrees to radians (example)", "size": 9800},
                                {"name": "How to convert from radians to degrees (example)", "size": 1314},
                                {"name": "Convert between degrees and radians", "size": 2220},

{"name": "Rotation by radians and quadrants"}
                            ]
                        },
                        {"name": "The Unit Circle Definition of Sine, Cosine and Tangent", "size": 1759,
                        "children": [
                        {"name": "The unit circle definition of sine, cosine, and tangent"},
                        {"name": "How to find trigonometric values using the unit circle definition (example)"},
                        {"name": "Find trig values using the unit circle definition"},
                        {"name": "Matching the SOH CAH TOA and the unit circle definitions of the trigonometric functions"}
                        ]
                        },
                        {"name": "The graphs of Sine, Cosine and Tangent", "size": 2165,
                        "children": [
                        {"name": "The graph of the sine function"},
                        {"name": "The graph of the tangent function"},
                        {"name": "Finding the intersection points of the graphs of sine and cosine"}
                        ]
                        },
                        {"name": "Basic Trigonometric Identities", "size": 586,
                        "children": [
                        {"name": "Sine and cosine identities that arise from the symmetry of the unit circle"},
                        {"name": "Tangent identities that arise from the symmetry of the unit circle"},
                        {"name": "Sine and cosine identities that arise from angle rotations on the unit circle"},
                        {"name": "Identity that arises from the periodicity of the tangent function"}
                        ]
                        },
                        {"name": "Trigonometric Values of Special Angles", "size": 3331,
                        "children": [
                        {"name": "Finding the trigonometric values of a special angle in the unit circle"},
                        {"name": "Find the trigonometric values of special angles"}
                        ]
                        },
                        {"name": "The Pythagorean Identity", "size": 772,
                        "children": [
                        {"name": "Proof of the Pythagorean trigonometric identity"},
                        {"name": "How to find a trig value of an angle given another trig value of the angle (example)"},
                        {"name": "Use the Pythagorean identity"}
                        ]
                        },
                        {"name": "Love live Tau", "size": 3322,
                        "children": [
                        {"name": "Tau versus Pi"},
                        {"name": "Pi is (still) wrong"}
                        ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Graphs of trigonometric functions",
                    "children": [
                        {"name": "The graphs of sine, cosine, and tangent", "size": 8833,
                        "children": [
                        {"name": "The graph of the sine function"},
                        {"name": "The graph of the tangent function"},
                        {"name": "Finding the intersection points of the graphs of sine and cosine"}
                        ]
                        },
                        {"name": "Introduction to amplitude, midline, and extrema of sinusoidal functions", "size": 1732,
                        "children": [
                        {"name": "Midline, amplitude and period of a sinusoidal function"},
                        {"name": "Find the midline of sinusoidal functions from their graph"},
                        {"name": "Find the amplitude of sinusoidal functions from their graph"}
                        ]
                        },
                        {"name": "Finding amplitude and midline of sinusoidal functions from their formulas", "size": 3623,
                        "children": [
                        {"name": "Find the midline of a sinusoidal function from its formula"},
                        {"name": "How to find the amplitude and period of a sinusoidal functions from its formula (example)"},
                        {"name": "Find the amplitude of a sinusoidal function from its formula"}
                        ]
                        },
                        {"name": "Period of sinusoidal functions", "size": 10066,
                        "children": [
                        {"name": "Find the period of sinusoidal functions from their graph"},
                        {"name": "How to find the amplitude and period of a sinusoidal functions from its formula (example)"},
                        {"name": "Find the period of a sinusoidal function from its formula"}
                        ]
                        },
                        {"name": "Graphing sinusoidal functions", "size": 10066,
                        "children": [
                        {"name": "Graph of a sinusoidal function with vertical stretch and horizontal reflection"},
                        {"name": "Graph of a sinusoidal function with vertical and horizontal stretches"},
                        {"name": "Graph sinusoidal functions"},
                        {"name": "Graph sinusoidal functions (including phase shift)"}
                        ]
                        },
                        {"name": "Constructing sinusoidal functions", "size": 10066,
                        "children": [
                        {"name": "How to construct a sinusoidal function from its graph"},
                        {"name": "Construct sinusoidal functions"},
                        {"name": "Word problem: Constructing a sinusoidal model using sine"},
                        {"name": "Word problem: Constructing a sinusoidal model using cosine"},
                        {"name": "Model situations with sinusoidal functions"},
                        {"name": "Word problem: Constructing a sinusoidal model with phase shift"},
                        {"name": "Model situations with sinusoidal functions (including phase shift)"}
                        ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Trigonometric equations and identities",
                    "children": [
                        {"name": "The inverse trigonometric functions", "size": 4116,
                        "children": [
                          {"name": "Introduction to arcsine"},
                          {"name": "Introduction to arctangent"},
                          {"name": "Introduction to arccosine"},
                          {"name": "Evaluate inverse trigonometric functions"},
                          {"name": "How to restrict the domain of a function to make it invertible (example)"},
                          {"name": "Restricting the domain of a tangent function to make it invertible"},
                          {"name": "How to find an angle given its tangent using a calculator (example)"}
                        ]
                        },
                      {"name": "Solving basic sinusoidal equations", "size": 4116,
                      "children": [
                        {"name": "How to find all solutions to an equation of the form sin(x)=d (example)"},
                        {"name": "Solving cos(θ)=1 and cos(θ)=-1"},
                        {"name": "Solve basic sinusoidal equations"}
                      ]
                      },
                      {"name": "Solving advanced sinusoidal equations", "size": 4116,
                      "children": [
                        {"name": "Solve advanced sinusoidal equations"}
                      ]
                      },
                      {"name": "Solving sinusoidal models", "size": 4116,
                      "children": [
                       {"name": "Word problem: Solving a sinusoidal modeling function"},
                        {"name": "Solve sinusodial modeling functions"}
                       ]
                      },
                      {"name": "Introduction to the trigonometric angle addition identities", "size": 4116,
                      "children": [
                        {"name": "Review of the trigonometric angle addition identities"},
                        {"name": "How to use the cosine angle addition identity (example)"},
                        {"name": "How to use the cosine double-angle identity (example)"},
                        {"name": "Practice using the trigonometric angle addition identities"},
                        {"name": "Proof of the sine angle addition identity"},
                        {"name": "Proof of the cosine angle addition identity"}
                      ]
                      },
                      {"name": "Using trigonometric identities to solve problems", "size": 4116,
                       "children": [
                       {"name": "How to find trigonometric values using the angle addition formulas (example)"},
                       {"name": "Use angle addition formulas to find trig values"},
                       {"name": "How to find a side length using the trig angle addition identities (example)"},
                       {"name": "How to manipulate expressions using the trig angle addition formulas (example)"},
                       {"name": "Rewriting trigonometric expressions using trigonometric identities"}
                       ]

                      },
                      {"name": "Challenging trigonometry problems",
                      "children": [
                        {"name": "Challenge problem: Find the area of a triangle"},
                        {"name": "Challenge problem: Find the area of a hexagon"},
                        {"name": "Challenge problem: Find cosine of sum of angles given their cosines"},
                        {"name": "Challenge problem: Rewrite a trigonometric equation of angles in arithmetic progression"},
                        {"name": "Challenge problem: Find the maximum value of a trigonometric expression"},
                        {"name": "Challenge problem: System of trigonometric equations"},
                        {"name": "Challenge problem: Conditions on angle for a system of equation having a solution"}
                      ]
                      }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Miscellaneous",
                    "children": [
                        {"name": "Trigonometry readiness warmup", "size": 1082,
                        "children": [
                          {"name": "Trigonometry Warmup"}
                          ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Old Content",
                    "children": [
                        {"name": "Trigonometry 0.5", "size": 1616},
                        {"name": "Trigonometry  1.5", "size": 1027},
                        {"name": "Reciprocal Trig Functions", "size": 3891},
                        {"name": "Trigonometric functions and side ratios in right triangles", "size": 891},
                        {"name": "Non-right Triangle Proofs", "size": 2893},
                        {"name": "Radians on the unit circle", "size": 5103},
                        {"name": "Radians and arc length", "size": 3677},
                        {"name": "Unit circle trigonometry", "size": 781},
                        {"name": "Symmetry and periodicity of trigonometric functions", "size": 4141},
                        {"name": "Understanding inverse trig functions", "size": 933},
                        {"name": "Understanding angle addition formulas", "size": 5130},
                        {"name": "Manipulating trig expressions with pythagorean identities", "size": 3617}                    ]
                }
            ]
        }];      
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) To change some styles or attributes for breadcrumbs edit these lines:

```
 entering.append("svg:polygon")
      .attr("points", breadcrumbPoints)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return 'red'; });
```

You can wrap the text element of your breadcrumb with a `<svg:a>` element in order to have a link over the breadcrumb:

```
.append("svg:a")
  // wrap text node in 'a' node      
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d){return d.url;})   // put here the right 'url' field (here url is defined for a few items)
      .append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", (b.w + b.t) / 2)
      .attr("x", (b.w + b.t) / 2)
      .attr("y", b.h / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

2) To change color set operates here:

```
$scope.options = {
            chart: {
                ...
                color: d3.scale.category20(),
```

More details on https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#category20

Finally check the CodePen forked and modified:

http://codepen.io/beaver71/pen/bEvYZN